# Split screen app for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, window-manager

I'm aware of [applications such as this](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/split-screen/id453757310?mt=12) which allow windows to be "halved", allowing the screen to be divided up. But are there any apps out there that split the Mac screen *within* applications and *within* windows? I'm aware that split screen editing is available in Microsoft Word and Excel, but is there an app which is allows a universal split screen across all applications?

Answer (score 1):

Put the same application on both sides, then select the window that you want in the left side and the other window in the right side.

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to split the screen within the same window - question edited

Answer (score 1):

Most Mac apps allow you to create duplicate windows of the same document, if they have a "New Window" menu item in the Window menu. You can then arrange these two windows of the same document (views of the same window, if you like) as you wish.

I think that's the best you're going to get natively without some additional software.

Answer (score -2):

Long press the fullscreen button, and then you will figure out the rest.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  While this is *technically* an answer it falls far short in the spirit of actually answering the question. Consider reviewing the [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) and reworking your answer.